# BitcoinJ how to understand receive Address?

Tags: bitcoinj

I need to receive bitcoins from the customers, and then add to theirs virtual account some credits. I use `BitcoinJ` wallet and I want to give each customer the unique Address created by

```
walletAppKit.wallet().freshReceiveAddress()
```

But when I receive coins I can't define customer who send me them.

`walletAppKit.wallet().addCoinsReceivedEventListener((w, tx, prevBalance, newBalance)` contains all information but I don't see any Address info to define customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many recipients (in the
same transaction), so you need to iterate for the correct ones. E.g. for
incoming transactions, you can do

```
for (TransactionOutput output : tx.getOutputs())
{
        try
        {
                if (output.isMine(wallet))
                {
                        Script script = output.getScriptPubKey();
                        Address address = script.getToAddress(Constants.NETWORK_PARAMETERS,true);
                        // do something with the address
                }
        }
        catch (final ScriptException x){}
}
```

Comment: Could you please explane isMine method?

Comment: This method Returns true if this output is to a key, or an address we have the keys for, in the wallet, Reference: https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.14/org/bitcoinj/core/TransactionOutput.html#isMine-org.bitcoinj.core.TransactionBag-

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with bitcoinj but it appears to me that you need to do the following.

You're passed the transaction that was received (`tx`).  Call [`getOutputs`](https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.14/org/bitcoinj/core/Transaction.html#getOutputs--) to get a list of the transaction's outputs, and for each one, call [`getAddressFromP2PKHScript`](https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.14/org/bitcoinj/core/TransactionOutput.html#getAddressFromP2PKHScript-org.bitcoinj.core.NetworkParameters-) to determine the address credited by that output.

You should account for the possibility that there might be multiple outputs paying the same address, or multiple outputs paying different addresses that are in your wallet.